# Ripple effect is not displaying in button in angular app - Angular-Material

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7

https://material.angular.io/components/button/overview

I am using this angular-material button but everything is working fine but I am not getting ripple effect onclick of button?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-lazy-loading-lnchhw?file=src/styles.css

I have produced it in stackblitz but its working fine but not in my angular app?

I am missing something or there is some bug?

### app.component.html

```
<button mat-button>Basic</button>
```

### app.module.ts

```
 import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material';
      imports: [
   BrowserModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        RouterModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        NgbModule.forRoot(),
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        NoopAnimationsModule
        MatButtonModule,
        MaterialModule
        ],
```

Comment: Got solution. NoopAnimationsModule is causing error, but can't understand why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't import both `BrowserAnimationsModule` and `NoopAnimationsModule`. You only want `BrowserAnimationsModule`.

`NoopAnimationsModule` essentially disables animations!

Comment: Thanks, I just found this.But can you please explain why? I can't understand this.

Comment: Answer has been updated - `NoopAnimationsModule` essentially disables animations.

Comment: Thanks.  G. Tranter. I will read about this NoopAnimationsModule.